Can't find or read the file on the SD card
I would like to read an XML file in my activity that I copied to an SD card.
If the file does not exist, I read the data from the string file. This part works.
I've tried and researched a lot, but unfortunately, I can't get anywhere. Maybe someone has the right tip for me?
My AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

In the MainActivity.java, under onCreate:
        // first check for runtime permission
        String permission = android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        }else {
            Log.v(TAG, "OnCreate(): grant is not READ_EXTERAL_STORAGE");
        }

        // Switch-Liste erstellen und an den View binden
        createSwitchlList();
        bindAdapterToListView();


In createSwitchList():
    private void createSwitchlList() {
        boolean fromFile = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "createSwitchList() entered.");

        //First check if the sd card is mounted or not
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            // sd card mounted
            Log.v(TAG, "SD-CARD is available");
        }

        String myFile = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyWifiDemo" + File.separator + "switch.xml").toString();
        if (myFile != null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Find path/file " + myFile);

            fromFile = true;

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

            try {

                dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(myFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                Log.v(TAG, "XML-root: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Read-XML-Document RuntimeExeption: " + e);
                fromFile = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Read-XML-Document Exeption: " + e);
                fromFile = false;
            }
        }
        if (!fromFile) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Path or file not found");

            String[] geradeOn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gerade_an);
            String[] geradeOff = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gerade_aus);
            String[] abzweigOn = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abzweig_an);
            String[] abzweigOff = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abzweig_aus);

            mSwitchListe.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < geradeOn.length; i++) {
                Switch newSwitch = new Switch(getString(R.string.dcc_address) + (i + 1),
                        getString(R.string.dcc_status_gerade), geradeOn[i], geradeOff[i],
                        abzweigOn[i], abzweigOff[i]);
                mSwitchListe.add(newSwitch);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acht Schalter erstellt, XML-Datei existiert nicht", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "*** Acht Schalter erstellt, XML-Datei existiert nicht");
        }
    }


And this is my log:
15:12:57.759 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  MainActivity Version 5.0.17
15:12:57.777 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  createSwitchList() entered.
15:12:57.780 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  SD-CARD is available
15:13:05.072 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  Find path/file /storage/emulated/0/MyWifiDemo/switch.xml
15:13:23.857 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  Read-XML-Document Exeption: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /storage/emulated/0/MyWifiDemo/switch.xml
15:13:28.351 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  Path or file not found
15:13:32.895 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  *** Acht Schalter erstellt, XML-Datei existiert nicht
15:13:32.905 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  2. Stufe: onStart() betreten
15:13:32.911 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  3. Stufe: onResume() betreten
15:13:33.293 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  4. Stufe: onPause() betreten
15:13:33.309 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  onRequestPermissionsResult: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission not granted. Result: -1

15:13:33.310 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  3. Stufe: onResume() betreten

15:13:40.663 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  4. Stufe: onPause() betreten

15:13:41.077 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  5. Stufe: onStop() betreten
15:13:41.085 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  --> Zustand speichern: onSaveInstanceState() betreten

15:13:44.884 MainActivity            de.dfwschmidts.mywifidemo            V  6. Stufe: onDestroy() betreten


anticipated path/file: SD-CARD/MyWifiDemo/switch.xml

External storage is not an SD card on most Android devices made in the past decade, and getExternalStorageDirectory() does not point to one if it exists. READ_EXTERAL_STORAGE is not a relevant permission on modern versions of Android. I recommend that you use the Storage Access Framework (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT / ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument) and let the user select the content for your app to. use.

I have read the description of the SAF. But I can't cope with it.
Even when looking for an example, I didn't really understand the connections.
Can anyone give me an example of how a file (*.xml) can be searched and read in a stream?

FWIW, I cover the Storage Access Framework in this free book. I also demonstrate its use in this free book, this free book, and some of the others. The documentation is here, and there are countless additional examples in Medium posts, GitHub projects, and elsewhere.

Thank you very much for the hints. After reading it for the first time, I think I'll get further with it.
For the time being, this is the end of the inquiry for me.
